# Youtube and other online videos will not play

Tags: google-chrome, video, flash, youtube

After some update which I did not note, All online videos will not play (both Chrome v. 77  and Firefox v.69 ).  I already installed flash plugin and
disabled Hardware acceleration in Chrome.  When I try to play video
only shows first screen, pressing play will just change the play button to pause button but not play the video.

I could navigate the video scenes though.  But it will not play.

Any other way to diagnose and solve this problem?

Comment: Please note that you don't need Flash for YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the google chrome remotedesktop.  Somehow now youtube and other video streaming works.